# Erro ao deserializar JSON (JSON array)

Tags: c#, json, .net, xamarin-forms

Procurei outros tópicos relacionados a esse erro, mas acredito que o meu caso seja um pouco diferente.

**Erro:**

> System.Exception: Erro ao processar solicitação: Cannot deserialize
>   the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Models.Pedido'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.

**Vamos do começo:**

Eu estou tentando realizar um POST e recebendo esse erro na aplicação.
Já não começa a fazer sentido esse erro, pois no post eu não realizo nenhuma desserialização.

Testando em um Motorola Z3 Play.

**Código que gera o erro:** *("client" é uma instância de HttpClient() )*

```
public async Task AddPedidoAsync(Pedido pedido)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "http://<endereço>:55580/api/Pedidos";
                string token = Preferences.Get("token", "default_value");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pedido);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Erro ao incluir pedido");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro na solicitação: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

**A classe "pedido":**

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdEstabelecimento { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public int IdStatus { get; set; }
    public int IdFormaPagamento { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorDesconto { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorEntrega { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorTroco { get; set; }
    public bool Recepcionado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataRecepcao { get; set; }
    public int IdPedidoMobile { get; set; }
}
```

**O que eu já testei:**

Ao debugar, inicialmente eu achei que o erro poderia ser por conta da estrutura do meu JSON no que diz respeito ao campo "DataPedido", que é um DateTime:

```
{\"Id\":0,
\"IdEstabelecimento\":1,
\"IdCliente\":1,
\"IdStatus\":1,
\"IdFormaPagamento\":1,
\"DataPedido\":\"2019-01-29T10:40:52.539523-02:00\",
\"ValorTotal\":220.99,
\"ValorDesconto\":0.0,
\"ValorEntrega\":0.0,
\"ValorTroco\":0.0,
\"Recepcionado\":false,
\"DataRecepcao\":null,
\"IdPedidoMobile\":2975}
```

Então eu alterei a minha classe de Pedido e converti a data para o formato sem os milissegundos. Nada feito.

**Pra concluir de maneira MUITO estranha:**

Se eu consultar na minha base de dados, o pedido foi postado corretamente!

[image: foto do BD]

Comment: Qual linha estoura o erro? Tá me parecendo um erro no serviço web e não no aplicativo. Btw, ao capturar uma exceção e lançar apenas a mensagem dela você **joga fora** toda informação relevante a respeito do erro.

Comment: Não precisa de ter um construtor sem paramentros na classe Pedido?

Comment: a linha é essa :  response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);... E você me deu uma ótima ideia na verdade... vou debugar a WebAPI pra ver o que acontece do lado de lá... muito obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: @LINQ, você estava certo meu amigo. O problema era no serviço... por mais que meu modelo tivesse DECLARADO que a DataRecepcao era do tipo ?DateTime, o serviço dava erro ao incluir reclamando do valor nulo. WA: Passo um valor qualquer e mudo pra nulo diretamente no Controller. (por hora)... MUITO obrigado!